# Finding and replacing text in the elements of a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to search all the elemetns of a Javascript object and replace every occurance of the text "???" with, say for example, "***".

An example of the JSON would be

```
{
    "page-title": "Tasks",
    "sections": [{
        "section-heading": "Work",
        "subsections": [{
            "subsection-heading": "First",
            "subsection-texts": [{
                "text": "This is some text."
            }]
        }, {
            "subsection-heading": "Second",
            "subsection-texts": [{
                "text": "This is some more text."
            }, {
                "text": "This is even more text ???."
            }]
        }, {
            "subsection-heading": "Third ???",
            "subsection-texts": [{
                "text": "This is the last text."
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

As you can see, the "???" text could be at different levels. So is there some way of searching and replacing every occurance of $???$ with "***"?

I am looking for a method that will check the actual JSON object elements, I do not want a method that stringifys the object and then uses regex. Can this be done efficiently?

Comment: A JSON object is a misnomer. You mean a JavaScript object or a JSON string?

Comment: @trincot ok I've changed it to Javascript object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through all object properties or array items with map/reduce and replace all question marks for strings:

```
var data = { ... }

function replaceQuestionMarks(obj) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        return obj.map(function(o) {
            return replaceQuestionMarks(o);
        })
    } else if (typeof obj === 'object') {
        return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(r, key) {
            r[key] = replaceQuestionMarks(obj[key]);
            return r;
        }, {})
    } else if (typeof obj === 'string') {
        return obj.replace('???', '***');
    }
    return obj;
}

var replaced = replaceQuestionMarks(data);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's works great! I was wondering is it possible to make it work if there is more than one occurrence of '???' in the string?

Comment: @sonicboom sure just use regex in replace function `obj.replace(/\?/g, '*');`

Comment: Actually I have just noticed an issue. The code works if the JSON data is in string form. But if the data is a Javascript object (for example, after parsing the data string with JSON.parse) then there is an error: ReferenceError: replace is not defined(…). It occurs on this line: r[key] = replace(obj[key]);

Comment: `typeof obj === 'array'` don't think that works. `typeof [] //object`

Comment: @sonicboom my fault, typo, I've just updated answer.

Comment: @madox2 Cheers for this code, it has saved me a lot of hassle!

Answer (score -3):

One approach would be to convert it to a string, replace the question marks with a regular expression and then parse back into an object:

```
var myObject = {...};
myObject = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject).replace(/\?\?\?/gi, '***')));
```

This might not be the best way to do it in terms of performance but we'd need more details about what you are actually doing. This may be just as efficient as other ways of doing it. How big are the objects on which you need to do this?

Comment: Read the last paragraph of the question.

Comment: haha... I guess I jumped the answer before finishing readiing. However, replacing the text that matches the string "???" with something else will required some amount of either manual parsing or a regex. It's possible that this approach will be more efficient than other approaches.

Comment: "either manual parsing or a regex" what do you mean? It's entirely feasable to just walk through all the values of the object and modify them as you see fit _without_ needing to treat the object as a string.

Comment: Let's hope the caller does not want to replace `{` with something else.

Comment: That's not what I meant. What I meant was, if you recursively traverse your object graph all the way down to all the properties that might have ???, you will then have to either do a replace() to convert them into *** or you would have to conditionally check each one with: if (theObj[propertyName] === '???') { theObj [propertyName] = '***';}